# Optimize solution runtime to 3Sum problem

Tags: python, runtime

I am trying to find all unique triplets within a given set of integers that sum to zero. I have the following code which to me works logically but I keep getting a timeout error. Any advice on what I am missing or how to optimize? I have gone over it several times and I can't see how to make it any faster. Thanks in advance!

```
class Solution:
def threeSum(self, nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: List[List[int]]
    """
    nums.sort()
    for i in range(len(nums)-2):
        if i > 0 and nums[i] == nums[i-1]:
            continue

        target = 0 - nums[i]
        j = i +1
        k = len(nums) - 1
        tgt_sum = 0
        trpls = []

        while j < k:
            tgt_sum = nums[j] + nums[k]
            if tgt_sum == target:
                x = []
                x.append([i,j,k])
                if all(item in trpls for item in x) == True:
                    trpls_list.append([i,j,k])
            elif tgt_sum < target:
                j += 1
            elif tgt_sum > target:
                k -= 1
            else:
                k -= 1

test = Solution()
given_nums = [-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]
print(test.threeSum(given_nums))
```

Comment: Python is just really really slow at finishing infinite loops.

Comment: smh. i'll just see myself out then...

Comment: @MikeBeaton In case of `if tgt_sum == target`, they're not changing `j` and `k`, so they loop infinitely.

Comment: there was no break for tgt_sum == target...so it just looped infinitely in that case.

Comment: lol nah @HeapOverflow 's response was hilarious, and the disdain totally called for. thanks again for the edit.

Comment: I'm not sure disdain is ever totally called for, and I wasn't giving disdain to what I thought was a mistake in your code, but to what I thought (wrongly, it seems) was an intentional but amusing misreading of your question... anyway, moving on... sorry!